# Smallest encoding for JSON containing binary data (and gzip compression)

Tags: json, encoding, escaping, base64, binary-data

What is the smallest (number of bytes) encoding for normally distributed binary data encapsulated in JSON and what character encoding for the containing JSON should be used in conjunction?
What encoding provides the smallest result when compressed with gzip?

```
{ 
  "data" : "########-THIS-IS-ALOT-OF-BINARY-DATA-##############...",
  "some-normal-data" : ...
}
```

E.g. base64, base85, URI-encoded, simply escaped \"